# Build \ maven clean + install bizarreness

Tags: spring, maven, build, controller

In my project i made the following change:

from:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public long getLogin(@RequestBody UserLoginData userData, HttpServletRequest request) {

logger.info(String.format(
              Constants.LogMessages.NEW_POST_REQUEST_FROM_IP,
              request.getRemoteAddr()));

logger.info("/login/");

long result = userService.getUserByUsernameAndPassword("", "");

return result;
}
```

to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public long getLogin(@RequestBody UserLoginData userData, HttpServletRequest request) {

logger.info(String.format(
              Constants.LogMessages.NEW_POST_REQUEST_FROM_IP,
              request.getRemoteAddr()));

logger.info("/login/");

long result = userService.getUserByUsernameAndPassword("", "");

return result;
}
```

(I change the mapping-requestMethod from POST to GET)
in one of my @controller

thing is - after i made the change, i restarted the tomcat.
and tried to call the controller GET method.
got an error: GET is not supported, but POST is supported.

meaning - the change didn't took place in my project build.

the bizarre thing is after i did project\maven\ run as maven-clean
and right afterwards - project\maven\ run as maven-install

the changes took place!

can anyone explain please why maven has anything to do with my project logic? i thought its for dependencies only...

p.s i got the "build automatically" options set to "true" and i use spring tool suite.

cheers

Comment: Restarting Tomcat does not rebuild the web applications deployed to it.

Comment: and rebuilding project?